# Crashlytics crashing with Xcode 10 when not launched using debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Our application crashes when it is built using Xcode 10 and Crashlytics, but works fine when built with Xcode 9 and Crashlytics.  Launching the app from Xcode works fine, but launching it from the iPhone itself will crash as soon as [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]; is executed.  Removing this line allows the app to launch successfully. Have the latest Crashlytics Framework.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FIRApp configure]; 
    [[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance] setLoggerLevel:FIRLoggerLevelMin];
    [FirebaseConfig sharedConfig];
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
    return YES;
}


Crashed: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x188eb5104 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x188f34a00 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 296
2  libsystem_c.dylib                     0x188e0cd78 abort + 140
3  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d591d4 __sanitizer::Abort() + 62
4  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d579cc __sanitizer::Die() + 174
5  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d41790 __asan::AsanCheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 266
6  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d57a54 __sanitizer::CheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 120
7  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d44370 __asan::AsanThread::SetThreadStackAndTls(__asan::AsanThread::InitOptions const*) + 238
8  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d43f24 __asan::AsanThread::Init(__asan::AsanThread::InitOptions const*) + 96
9  libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib    0x103d44394 __asan::AsanThread::ThreadStart(unsigned long long, __sanitizer::atomic_uintptr_t*) + 36
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x188f392fc _pthread_body + 128
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x188f3925c _pthread_start + 48
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x188f3cd08 thread_start + 4


com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188eb59fc __ulock_wait + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x188d26e4c _dispatch_ulock_wait
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x188d26db8 _dispatch_wait_on_address$VARIANT$armv81
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x188d27834 _dispatch_group_wait_slow
4  TheApp                          0x102327308 CLSContextInitialize + 772
5  TheApp                          0x102324474 -[CLSCrashReportingController installCrashReportingHandlers:] + 24
6  TheApp                          0x10232376c -[CLSCrashReportingController startCrashReporterWithAPIKey:betaToken:profilingMark:report:] + 608
7  TheApp                          0x102323378 -[CLSCrashReportingController startWithProfilingMark:betaToken:] + 304
8  TheApp                          0x102317cec __20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke + 636
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x188d58484 _dispatch_client_callout
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x188d28260 _dispatch_once_callout
11 TheApp                          0x102317a6c -[Crashlytics start] + 104
12 TheApp                          0x102317e98 +[Crashlytics initializeIfNeeded] + 48
13 TheApp                          0x10234c0b4 __15+[Fabric with:]_block_invoke + 520
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x188d58484 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x188d28260 _dispatch_once_callout
16 TheApp                          0x10234bea8 +[Fabric with:] + 224
17 TheApp                          0x100666608 -[TheAppAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (TheAppAppDelegate.m:173)
18 UIKitCore                      0x1b5bca5f8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
19 UIKitCore                      0x1b5bcbd60 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3340
20 UIKitCore                      0x1b5bd17ac -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1552
21 UIKitCore                      0x1b63f8db8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784
22 UIKitCore                      0x1b63f5364 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
23 UIKitCore                      0x1b63f8a34 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240
24 UIKitCore                      0x1b63f93d4 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1076
25 UIKitCore                      0x1b63b85fc __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 772
26 UIKitCore                      0x1b63b82a8 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
27 UIKitCore                      0x1b63fb844 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
28 UIKitCore                      0x1b63fc334 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
29 UIKitCore                      0x1b63fb6fc -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
30 UIKitCore                      0x1b63f4a10 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
31 UIKitCore                      0x1b5bcfca4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
32 UIKitCore                      0x1b5c0145c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
33 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd4f890 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
34 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd5a658 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 260
35 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd59d50 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
36 libdispatch.dylib              0x188d58484 _dispatch_client_callout
37 libdispatch.dylib              0x188d2f3f0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81
38 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd8e640 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
39 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd8e2cc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 416
40 FrontBoardServices             0x18bd8e8e8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
41 CoreFoundation                 0x1892ae5b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
42 CoreFoundation                 0x1892ae538 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
43 CoreFoundation                 0x1892ade1c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
44 CoreFoundation                 0x1892a8ce8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1040
45 CoreFoundation                 0x1892a85b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
46 GraphicsServices               0x18b51c584 GSEventRunModal + 100
47 UIKitCore                      0x1b5bd3558 UIApplicationMain + 212
48 TheApp                          0x1015042bc main (main.m:14)
49 libdyld.dylib                  0x188d68b94 start + 4
```

Comment: Can you please share your Fabric init code and any conditional logic around it?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I updated the post with the Fabric init code

Comment: Gotcha and you're trying to set this up from Fabric and not Firebase or vice versa? If from Firebase, it is a new to Firebase app or had it used Crashlytics before?

Comment: We have been using Fabric for a long time, we added Firebase about a year ago.  This had been all working just fine until we moved from Xcode 9 to 10.  If we build with Xcode 9 all works fine.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Which version of Fabric and Crashlytics are you running?

Comment: Crashlytics 3.10.7 and Firebase Analytics v.50001000

Comment: Thanks, can you try this order, Fabric before Firebase: 
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
    [FIRApp configure]; 
    [[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance] setLoggerLevel:FIRLoggerLevelMin];
    [FirebaseConfig sharedConfig];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180464/discussion-between-tingo-and-mike-bonnell).

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 can you please provide similar information such as the version of Xcode, Crashlytics and Fabric frameworks and your setup.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Xcode 10, latest Crashlytics and Fabric pods

Comment: Can you share your Firebase and Fabric init code?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?  I submitted bug report to support@fabric.io but I have not received any response.

Comment: In my case the "Address Sanitizer" option in Xcode was enabled in the scheme for the debug build.  Turning this off solved the crash.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using Xcode10.0 (10A255), Crashlytics 3.11.0 (133), Firebase 5.10.0.